# How to set the position of an object/element at the center of Webpage when performing click method using HP UFT

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I want to click/select an object which is not visible in the browser. Now, my first step is to use the **.Object.scrollIntoView** then **.Click** method  to make the object visible in my browser and click it.

But, it won't work as I have a static on-scroll header in my Webpage which block the element and causes it not be able to click.

See below for reference.

Step 1: Show item by using **.Object.scrollIntoView**

- The box in **red** is the on-scroll static web page header. Now, I want to select the **item N: Non-redundant** in the **System Type section**.
- The **item N: Non-redundant** was shown in the web page by using 
  **Browser("").Page("").Element("").Object.scrollIntoView**

[image]

Step 2: Click/Select item.

- I added the item in my object repository and highlight it to see what is happening and when I try to highlight it, you can notice on the box in **red** that the item was scrolled to the top and it is now blocked by the header which made the item unable to click.
- That's what happen when **Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2**, when I set it to **1**, the item is not clicked.

[image]

Anyone knows how can I make the UFT put the web element at the center of the webpage when I perform the .Click method. Not on the top of the webpage.

Already tried these below methods but none of it was able to work.

```
Browser("").Page("").Element("").Click
Browser("").Page("").Element("").Click 0, 80
Browser("").Page("").Element("").FireEvent "OnMouseClick"
Browser("").Page("").Element("").Object.scrollIntoView
```

Thanks.

Comment: The `Click` method should scroll the object into view by itself. Can you share the web-page under question to see why it doesn't work?

Comment: Yeah, it automatically scroll to the object. But in my case, it put the object to the top and since I have a on-scroll static header, the object is blocked and made the UFT  can't click it. Please see the edited question, thank you.

Comment: I assume `Click.Object.scrollIntoView` is a typo (the `Click` shouldn't be there). Try `Element(..).Object.scrollInfoView false` so that it's scrolled [to the bottom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

Comment: I changed it. Sorry, didn't notice that one. Yeah, I tried Element(..).Object.scrollInfoView false expecting to disable the autoscroll and it didn't work also.

Comment: Right... After you scroll the `Click` will scroll it into (out of) view... I suggest contacting UFT's support. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Okay, will do. Thank you for the help.